# CALayer hides the imageView

Tags: ipad, imageview, calayer

Hai all am using CALayer to mask the UIImage, when i add the layer on imageview it display only layer portion hides remanning all image with white color filled

```
        CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
        mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"] CGImage];
        mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, mainImageWidth+30, mainImageHeight);
        mask.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
        mask.shadowOpacity = 1.5;

        mainImageView.layer.mask = mask;


        [mainImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
```

it hides my image view except the layer portion. how do i solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of create mask using image view  i have added three mask for UIView now its working perfect

```
 mainLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, mainImageWidth, mainImageHeight);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:mainLayer];
 mainLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;


secondLayer.frame = CGRectMake(gloss_x, gloss_y, gloss_w, gloss_h);
maskLayer = [CALayer layer];

UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
maskLayer.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;
maskLayer.frame =  maskRect;//CGRectMake(gloss_x, gloss_y-50, gloss_w, gloss_h);



secondLayer.contents = (id)s_glossImage.CGImage;


[mainLayer addSublayer:secondLayer];

mainLayer.mask = maskLayer;


[mainImageView.layer addSublayer:mainLayer];
```

Now its working fine.